# What are Ruby on Rails Controller Parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

What are the parameters sent by rails when they are sending them via hash as seen in the terminal while the server is running? This is the section in the terminal I'm talking about.

```
Started POST "/topics/2/feeds" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-01 21:01:17 -0700
Processing by FeedsController#create as JS
# HERE...
Parameters: {"feed"=>{"text"=>"Hello!"}, "commit"=>"Create Feed", "topic_id"=>"2"}
```

In the [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) they just say it is a query string in the url or POST data, but is it just Ruby code? Can it be JSON?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think it might just be language-agnostic HTTP verb data (like with `GET` or `POST`), not Ruby code. What do you mean "can it be JSON"? If you want to pass JSON to the controller, you could either `POST` it, or send it as a url query parameter with a `GET`, though you might need to url-encode it first in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a hash. What you see in the console, `Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}`, is simply the representation of the parameters for human readability. In the particular case you present, the parameter is given in the url:

```
GET /topics/2
```

If you look into your `config/routes.rb`, you will probably find a line like:

```
resources :topics
```

That means that the  `TopicsController` will be treated as a resource, and when you make this request,

```
GET /topics/2
```

Rails will interpret it that you are asking for a topic resource with id `2`. So the request will be pointed to the method `show` of your controller, and your `params` hash will have an `id` key with value `2`.

Read about [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are a simple hash that is received from the client, either via the query string or as POST data, just as the doc states. To access it in a controller, Rails makes the `params` hash available.

For your example above, you can simply use `params[:id]` to get the value `2`. Rails will have some keys and values by default if you use the Rails forms. Others you can specify on the client, usually using some sort of ajax query.